# C++ equivalent of Python difference_update?

Tags: c++, python, stdset

s1 and s2 are sets (Python set or C++ std::set)
To add the elements of s2 to s1 (set union), you can do

```
Python: s1.update(s2)

C++: s1.insert(s2.begin(), s2.end());
```

To remove the elements of s2 from s1 (set difference), you can do

```
Python: s1.difference_update(s2)
```

What is the C++ equivalent of this? The code

```
s1.erase(s2.begin(), s2.end());
```

does not work, for s1.erase() requires iterators from s1.The code

```
std::set<T> s3;
std::set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), std::inserter(s3, s3.end());
s1.swap(s3);
```

works, but seems overly complex, at least compared with Python.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: +1 nice question! I'm pretty sure that this could be done using `std::for_each`, but still not sure how exactly.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like `for_each` will not help here .. not even BOOST_FOREACH :\\

Comment: You could do BOOST_FOREACH(const T& t, s2) s1.erase(t);

Comment: Doh! Of course you could use it, as you only need the value, not the iterator..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `std::set_difference` is the idiomatic way to do this in C++.  You have stumbled across one of the primary differences (pun intended) between C++/STL and many other languages.  STL does not bundle operations directly with the data structures.  This is why `std::set` does not implement a difference routine.

Basically, algorithms such as `std::set_difference` write the result of the operation to another object.  It is interesting to note that the *algorithm* does not require that either or both of the operands are actually `std::set`.  The definition of the algorithm is:

> **Effects**: Copies the elements of the range `[first1, last1)` which are not present in the range `[first2, last2)` to the range beginning at `result`.  The elements in the constructed range are sorted.
>
> **Requires**: The resulting range shall not overlap with either of the original ranges.  Input ranges are required to be order by the same `operator<`.
>
> **Returns**: The end of the constructed range.
>
> **Complexity**: At most `2 * ((last1 - first1) + (last2 - first2)) - 1` comparisons

The interesting difference is that the C++ version is applicable to any two sorted ranges.  In most languages, you are forced to coerce or translate the calling object (left-hand operand) into a set before you have access to the *set difference* algorithm.

This is not really pertinent to your question, but this is the reason that the various *set* algorithms are modeled as free-standing algorithms instead of member methods.

Answer (score 4):

You should iterate through the second set:

```
for( set< T >::iterator iter = s2.begin(); iter != s2.end(); ++iter )
{
    s1.erase( *iter );
}
```

This <strike>will</strike> *could* be cheaper than using `std::set_difference` - `set_difference` copies the unique objects into a new container, but it takes *linear* time, while `.erase` will not copy anything, but is `O(n * log( n ) )`.

In other words, depends on the container, you could choose the way, that will be faster for your case.

Thanks  `David Rodríguez - dribeas` for the remark! (:

---

**EDIT**: Doh! I thought about BOOST_FOREACH at the very beginning, but I was wrong that it could not be used.. - you don't need the iterator, but just the value.. As user763305 said by himself/herself.

Comment: Whether this is cheaper or more expensive than `set_difference` depends on the inputs. For two large equal sets `set_difference` is linear in the size of the sets, but this approach is `O(N log N)` (for each element in one set, perform a lookup in the other set)

Comment: I have implemented an efficient (as efficient as it gets) version of in-place difference. It becomes *a little* more complex than this code though...

Comment: Nice (: +1 from me for the implementation.

Answer (score 4):

In c++ there is no `difference` method in the set. The `set_difference` looks much more awkward as it is more generic than applying a difference on two sets. Of course you can implement your own version of in place difference on sets:

```
template <typename T, typename Compare, typename Allocator>
void my_set_difference( std::set<T,Compare,Allocator>& lhs, std::set<T,Compare,Allocator> const & rhs )
{
    typedef std::set<T,Comapre,Allocator> set_t;
    typedef typename set_t::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename set_t::const_iterator const_iterator;

    const_iterator rit = rhs.begin(), rend = rhs.end();
    iterator it = lhs.begin(), end = lhs.end();
    while ( it != end && rit != rend )
    {
        if ( lhs.key_comp( *it, *rit ) ) {
            ++it;
        } else if ( lhs.key_comp( *rit, *it ) ) {
            ++rit;
        } else {
            ++rit;
            lhs.erase( it++ );
        }
    }
}
```

The performance of this algorithm will be linear in the size of the arguments, and require no extra copies as it modifies the first argument in place.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with `remove_if` writing your own functor for testing existence in a set, e.g.

```
std::remove_if(s1.begin(), s1.end(), ExistIn(s2));
```

I suppose that `set_difference` is more efficient though as it probably scans both sets only once

Answer (score 1):

Python set is unordered, and is more of an equivalent of C++ std::unordered_set than std::set, which is ordered.

David Rodríguez's algorithm relies on the fact that std::set is ordered, so the lhs and rhs sets can be traversed in the way as exhibit in the algorithm.

For a more general solution that works for both ordered and unordered sets, Kiril Kirov's algorithm should be the safe one to adopt if you are enforcing/preserving the "unorderedness" nature of Python set.